# How format Date in Ruby Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am using the Ruby Quickstart Code from Google (https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/ruby).
I now want to format the date for a whole day. But I can't format the date:

Thats the code:

````
      {
        title: e.summary,
        start: e.start.date || e.start.date_time.strftime('%d.%m.%y %H:%M clock|%A')
      }
```
When I add strftime to "e.start.date", e.g. "e.start.date.strftime('%d.%m.%y %H:%M clock|%A')", I get the following error: 
undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError).

How can I format the date? The date is currently in RFC3339
````

Comment: Can you double check if the `e.start.date` exists or is not empty? According to [NoMethodError for nil:NilClass](https://dev.to/ben/nomethoderror-undefined-method-for-nil-nilclass-explained-422b#) it happens when a method or attribute for an object you are trying to call does not exist. Or Can you confirm if your `e.start.date` will indeed return an FRC3339 date? This is because based on the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events), `start.date` is in the format "yyyy-mm-dd" & if this is an all-day event. [See image here](https://imgur.com/a/YZGXwwo).

Comment: Hello @IrvinJayG.
The Output for an all-day event is: EventDateTime:0x000002407232b9c8 @date=#<Date: 2022-04-17 ((2459687j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)
So, I think it isn't RFC3339 correct?

Comment: Can you try using `Date.parse` like this `Date.parse(e.start.date).strftime('%d.%m.%y %H:%M clock|%A')` & see how it will go? Perhaps the output isn't represented as a **DateTime Object**, thus `strftime` doesn't work.

Comment: RFC3339 format should be something like this `2019-10-12T07:20:50.52Z`. So, I doubt if the output is in that format. It looks to me that the output you've provided is a **String object**

Comment: Hi, I add this, and I got this error now: 
'parse': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)

Comment: I found something out: If I use a calendar with all-day events only, it work with this: ```start: e.start.date.strftime('%A') || e.start.date_time.strftime('%d.%m.%y|%A')``` When I add a normal event with time I got the same error

Comment: Yeah, all-day events output is in the format "yyyy-mm-dd", while a normal event that contains date and time is in RFC3339 format based on the official docs. It seems the output is a [`nil`](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/01/ruby-nil/) value, which means it is an empty value when being used in `Date.parse`.

Comment: Okay, but why does it work if there is no normal event?

Comment: All-day event (in the "yyyy-mm-dd" format) returns a Date Object that's why it works. On my testing, if an output is in RFC3339, it can be parsed using `Date.parse` then it can be used with `strftime` as seen [here](https://imgur.com/a/1FNeCvo).

Comment: Hmmm okay. And what can I do now? [link](https://imgur.com/a/kntYxFy)